# Post-Keynesian theory and households?

Tags: money, keynesian-economics, classical-economics

**"money must be introduced as part of the production process. Such a process is inherently dynamic, as entrepreneurs in each period must produce a new flow of commodities.” and households have no role to play in the creation of credit.** Is this view the Post-Keynesian view or the neoclassical view?

Comment: Hi @emma. Could you provide a reference?

Comment: @EB3112 Quoted text is from [Lavoie 1984](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4225471).

Answer (score -1):

This possible answer is from a 2004 Working Paper by Gennaro Zezza, Some Simple, Consistent Models of the Monetary Circuit.

http://www.levyinstitute.org/pubs/wp405.pdf

> The  Theory  of  the  Monetary  Circuit  (TMC)  has  received  a  growing  interest  among  post-Keynesians  in  the  last  two  decades.  New  developments  have  recently  appeared  from
> contributors to the two conferences in honor of Augusto Graziani,1 and a detailed analysis has recently appeared in Graziani (2003), where this approach is compared both to the classical
> and neoclassical tradition, and to other post-Keynesian approaches.

> **TMC, Say’s Law And The Keynesian Approach**
> At a first look, the TMC outlined here may resemble the neoclassical approach, where it is
> savings  decision  to  determine  investment,  rather  than  the  Keynesian  approach  of  effective
> demand,  where  investment  decisions  determine  the  level  of  output.  As  shown  in  our
> accounting  in  Tables  1  and  2,  investment  needs  to  be  financed  by  issuing  equities,  and
> demand  for  equities  ultimately  arises  from  savings,  so  it  may  seem  that  saving  decisions
> ultimately determine investment.
> Even  though  we  consistently  used  the  assumption  that  supply  equals  demand,  we
> believe TMC to be compatible with a Keynesian approach: assuming that firms have excess
> capacity,  an  increase  in  investment  will  stimulate  an  equal  increase  in  the  production  of
> capital  goods.  This  will  in  turn  require  an  increase  in  the  wage  bill  for  the  capital  goods
> sector, and an equivalent increase in loans demanded by this sector. The increase in the wage
> bill  will  stimulate  production  in  the  consumption  goods  sector,  following  the  standard
> multiplier  effect.  TMC  is  thus  entirely  Keynesian  in  spirit,  but  stresses  that  increases  in
> production, generated by a rise in effective demand, may be constrained by credit rationing, if
> firms pay real wages in advance.

Note: I have removed my original comments which are tangential to the question.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question? Am I missing something?

Comment: As an engineer I am more interested in the assumptions and model dynamics. I leave it to the economists to put labels on their models such as Post Keynesian or neoclassical. But in my opinion it is Post-Keynesian derived from the Italian banking circuit theory.